# Lists: Show image overlay on mouse over

Tags: sharepoint-list, json-formatting

I'm customizing a gallery view in a SharePoint list containing employee photos. Now I want to overlay a magnifier icon (via the Fluent Icon library) when visitors hover over the image with the mouse.

[image]

(**left:** normal image, **right:** when hovering with mouse)

I found something similar for backgrounds provided by a predefined class but this changes only the color of the element.

Comment: You want to add icon in gallery view using JSON? Or you want to show the image in card on hover? Can you please show us any example (link/screenshot) of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Something like this. https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ncdPdyCZLbU/maxresdefault.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you need, but here is a good start.

In order to display a custom hover card, you need to use `customCardProps` element. [See more details here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTenu.png). It has the following properties:

**openOnEvent**

- hover - card appears on mouse hover;
- click - card appears on click on the field.

**directionalHint**

- topCenter bottomCenter leftCenter rightCenter
- isBeakVisible - boolean. if true the card has a beak.

**How to display an image using JSON formatting**

```
{ 
  "elmType": "img",
  "attributes": {
    "src":  "[$Photo]" 
  }
}
```

**And here is a complete script**

```
{
    "elmType": "div",    
    "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Search"
    },
    "customCardProps": {
        "openOnEvent": "hover",
        "directionalHint": "rightCenter",
        "isBeakVisible": true,
        "formatter": {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style":{ "display": "block", "font-size": "15px", "padding": "10px" },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "style": { "display": "block", "width":"100%", "text-align": "center", "padding": "10px" },
                      "children":[
                      { "elmType": "img",
                            "attributes": {
                                "src":  "[$Photo]" 
                            }
                      }
                      ]
                   
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but as you mentioned, that's not what I was looking for. But combining your solution with my idea should work out great. :)

I edited my post with an example.